# How to use several copies of one activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications

My application creates notification for each SMS received:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning)
    .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notif_title))
    .setContentText(sms_from+": "+sms_body);
Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, DialogActivity.class);
mIntent.putExtra("sms_body", sms_body);
mIntent.putExtra("sms_from", sms_from);
mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent mPendingIntent =
    PendingIntent.getActivity(
    context,
    0,
    mIntent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
);          
mBuilder.setContentIntent(mPendingIntent);
```

Once user clicks notification, `DialogActivity` is opened, when I extract the data:

```
public class DialogActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final String sms_body = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sms_body");
        final String sms_from = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sms_from");
```

It works fine for one SMS/notification. But if more than one SMS is received, then `sms_from` and `sms_body` extracted at `onCreate` always contains the text of last SMS. How should I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` from your PendingIntent.

What is doing is updating the previous intent with the new values you're putting.

Also, you should use a different value (other than zero) for each new SMS

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean second parameter of getActivity by zero (requestCode)?

Comment: yes. PendingIntents get stored in separate area of the system and they are identified through those request codes. So if you put a new PendingIntent with the same request code, it overrides the previous one.

Comment: Strange - the doc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html says that it is not currently used.

Comment: Damn docs. Google "android pendingintent requestcode" what you'll see. The docs are really out of date.

Comment: Thanks, Budius, you are right. I've tested it with zero `requestCode` and it didn't work. But it works well with unique value.